# SonataMediaBundle and Pixlr Integration

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I'm stuck on this. **Pixlr Integration** in sonatamediabundle.

[in the documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-2/doc/reference/extra.html#pixlr-integration):

```
    # app/config/sonata_media.yml
sonata_media:
    # ...
    pixlr:
        enabled:  true
        secret:   theSecretHash
        referrer: Application Name
```

But I have no idea **where I get the data to fill "referrer" and "secret"**, Can you help me?